# error"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'scrollLeft' of undefined or null reference" while finding scroll position

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using below code to retrieve the scroll position of panel and gridview inside the content page after postback. I also use update panel. Below code work properly but it's throwing runtime javascript error like "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'scrollLeft' of undefined or null reference" on line 7, due to that autocomplete extender in the same page not functioning properly. Please help me to get rid of this javascript error so that both functions will work properly. Thanks in advance..

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        xPos = $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollLeft;//line 7
        yPos = $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollTop;
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
</script>`
```

Comment: `$('.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1')` maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly tagged this against JQuery, SO I am assuming you are using JQUERY.

you should be looking to do some thing like this

```
 xPos = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for sharing all your valuable ideas..

I have added one validation before executing each function, that resolved my issue. Please find the updated code below;`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {


        if ($get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1') != null) {
            xPos = $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollLeft;
            yPos = $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollTop;
        }
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if ($get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1') != null) {
            $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollLeft = xPos;
            $get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_Panel1').scrollTop = yPos;
        }
    }
</script>
```